# Как прочитать бинарный файл с конца

Tags: c++, файлы, ввод, файловый-ввод-вывод, binary-file

У меня есть задание, где мне надо выписать из бинарного файла числа в обратном порядке. вроде поставил флажок правильно, но оно отказывается даже читать. Хотя если работать от начала к концу файла, то всё нормально.
Помогите разобраться как правильно флажок поставить, или что ещё можно вообще сделать, чтобы оно читало с конца.

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name1[6] = "f.dbl";
    char name2[256];
    int a = 0;
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Input file name: ";
    cin >> name2;

    ifstream fInp;
    fInp.open(name1, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!fInp)
    {
        cout << "Error of opening of a input-file "
            << name1;
        cout << "\nPress any key to exit.\n";
        _getch();
        return 1;
    }

    ofstream fOut;
    fOut.open(name2, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!fOut)
    {
        cout << "Error of opening of a output-file "
            << name2;
        return 1;
    }

    while (fInp.read((char*)&a, sizeof(a)))
    {
        n++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fInp.seekg(-4L*i, ios::end);
        fInp.read((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
        if (a%2 == 0 && i%2 != 0)
        {
            fOut1.write((char*)&a, sizeof(a));
        }
    }


    fOut.close();
    fInp.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: После выхода из цикла `while (fInp.read((char*)&a, sizeof(a)))` файл в состоянии fail — после невозможности прочесть. Его надо опять "[привести в чувства](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)", прежде чем читать. Никаких операций с файлом в состоянии ошибки не делается...

Answer (score 1):

После выхода из цикла

```
while (fInp.read((char*)&a, sizeof(a)))
```

файл находится в состоянии ошибки после невозможности прочесть очередное значение. Никакие операции с файлом в состоянии ошибки не выполняются...

Файл надо опять "[привести в чувства](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear)", прежде чем читать.